# c# - Error Invalid requestMask.includeFields path while executing People API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-people-api

I am creating a web application in vs2017 for Enabling Google Authentication. I have a Login.aspx page where on button click following code is called:

```
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
         // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:53028/1.aspx');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');            
        xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
    }
```

This shows me google login screen and i am able to sign-in.

Code on 1.aspx.cs page:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.People.v1;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.People.v1.Data;

        UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
               new ClientSecrets
               {
                   ClientId = "1ghchabasa5.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                   ClientSecret = "AG0LvA1wZA11D"
               },
               new[] { "profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" },
               "me",
               CancellationToken.None).Result;

        // Create the service.
        var service = new PeopleService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Ms_Test",
        });

        PeopleResource.GetRequest peopleRequest = service.People.Get("people/me");
        peopleRequest.RequestMaskIncludeField = "person.names, person.emailAddresses";
        Person profile = peopleRequest.Execute(); // Error on this line
```

I want to get the email address and birthday of the signed-in user.

The error I am getting is :

> Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>
> Invalid requestMask.includeFields path: " person.email_addresses". [400]
>
> Errors [
>
> Message[Invalid requestMask.includeFields path: " person.email_addresses".] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]

Answer (score 0):

Tip: field is comma separated remove your space.

To get birthday you should be using birthdays

```
peopleRequest.RequestMaskIncludeField = "person.emailAddresses,person.birthdays";
```

If the data you are looking for isnt present make sure to have the user fill out [Personal info](https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info)

**Scopes**

Make sure that you have the proper scopes added in your code

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Example

```
new[] { "profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email" },
```

**test it**

If you run the following form you will see if the data exists or not [Test me](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/people/v1/people.people.get?resourceName=people%252Fme&requestMask.includeField=person.emailAddresses%252Cperson.birthdays&_h=2&)   When i run it i can see my birthday and my email address.

Comment: Getting error - 'PeopleResource.GetRequest' does not contain a definition for 'PersonFields' and no extension method 'PersonFields' accepting a first argument of type 'PeopleResource.GetRequest' could be found

Comment: There you go try it now.  Just remove the space you had

Comment: email address and birthday still shows null in profile, please advise

Comment: If the user has not filled in this information then the data will be null.  It is filled in on my account so it returns properly

Comment: email address is there as they are signing it with it and i have specified the age as well.

Comment: check your scopes make sure you have requested profile and email

Comment: How, please advise

Comment: new[] { "profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly" },   add email but its not going to help you get information that hasnt been hadded

Comment: This line is already in my code, still i am not getting any value related to email and birthday in profile object

Comment: Yes but as i mentioned you need to add the additional scopes to that line.  The scopes the user grants you permission to defines what data you will have access to.  If the user hasnt granted you permission to access it then you cant please read the anwser again.

Comment: This is strange when I click on https://myaccount.google.com/personal-info I can see the info in birthday, gender, email. Also when I click Test me it shows me the Birthday and email id, But in code both Birthday and email address are null, any idea why it is so? I have written the same code as specified above with your updates.

Comment: @DalmTo - can you please look at this please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55398286/c-sharp-people-api-does-not-return-email-address#_=_

Answer (score 0):

In Google People API
We need to give one of the Following :

- PersonFields
- RequestMaskIncludeField

I was also getting the same error for emailAddresses, I Used `PersonFields`,
You May Try Using PersonFields the following way:

```
var peopleService = new PeopleServiceService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                        {
                            ApplicationName = "App.Test",
                            HttpClientInitializer = userCredential
                        });
var peopleResource = new PeopleResource(peopleService);
var thisPersonRequest = peopleResource.Get("people/me");
            
thisPersonRequest.PersonFields = "emailAddresses,phoneNumbers,names,nicknames,genders";
            
thisPerson =  await thisPersonRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

Wher UserCredentials can be fetched Using IAuthorizationFlow.